# What human speech sounds could the canine vocal tract produce?

Tags: phonology, constructed-language

If dogs had brains with the same capacity for language as humans, but retained their canine vocal tracts, what human speech sounds could they produce?  And what speech sounds could they produce that humans could not?

Comment: When dogs bark, they do it by breathing in, not out like we do when we speak, so their language would probably consist of only implosive sounds))).

Comment: This is a better question for [Worldbuilding.SE] rather than Linguistics.

Comment: That one fact about dogs is useful and gives me much to ponder.

I didn't think answers would be almost entirely based on opinions because I believed the anatomy of phoneme production to be straightforward. So a comparison of dog anatomy to human anatomy should allow one to sort the phonemes used by humans in two: those that could and those that could not appear in Dogspeak and vice versa.

Comment: I disagree that this is an opinion-based question. It's a really hard question, and I doubt anyone here can compute the answer, but with sufficient knowledge of dog physiology, one can compute vocal tract configurations and acoustic outputs, and map them to human language analogs.

Comment: Data: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xEtE3KCWiPA

Comment: Thank you for posting that tantalizing link to the talking dog and to all posters. You have renewed my determination to proceed with the project.